# Alternatives for SSMS solutions & projects?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-tools

According to the official [SQL Server Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173803(v=sql.105).aspx), the use of "Solutions, Projects, and Items" is deprecated.  A conspicuous (though somewhat cryptic) warning banner at the top of the MSDN page states:

> "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."

Unfortunately, no suggestions for alternative storage/container strategies are offered. So what is the recommended way for storing and packaging the various scripts, queries, and files that make up your database application? I would also be very interested to know if any of you are acually using the Solutions or Projects framework in your current work, and what you use them for.

[Note: I realize that I could use VS2010 for this functionality, but I am interested in SSMS-based approaches (for the reasons expressed in the answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/why-should-i-use-visual-studio-2010-over-ssms-for-my-database-development)).]

Comment: Red Gate: [Tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/), [Sample Process](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/working-with-continuous-integration-in-a-bi-environment-using-red-gate-tools-with-tfs/)

Answer (score 7):

Reading between the lines, I guess the expectation/plan was for the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) (SSDT) project type to be extended to SSMS for the release of SQL 2012. Evidently that didn't happen, so we're stuck with the (frankly dreadful) SSMS interpretation of a project.

If you want something to manage your database source, you should be diving deep into SSDT. I'm currently using it for one greenfield project and also moving a large brownfield database to it. Minor niggles and pain points but no show stoppers and we're getting payback on the time invested already.

[Jamie Thomson](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/), who blogged extensively on VS2010 Database Projects (the predecessor), has started to publish articles on SSDT and appears to be as big a fan as I am. [Bob Beauchemin](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/) is another early adopter worth following.

If you want to organise a collection of random scripts (rather than a full database build) you can but support isn't quite "first-class". To do so, create a standard SSDT project type and change your scripts to compilation type "None" in the file properties.

Comment: SSDT works in the Visual Studio environment. While I'm sure it is powerful and useful, I am looking for a SSMS-based approach to this issue, as I expained in my Note above.

Answer (score 0):

Here at Red Gate we've just released a build of SQL Source Control that works alongside SSDT, providing a way to manage and source control database changes from SQL Server Management Studio, working against the database project repository.

More details and a download link can be found on the SSDT forums themselves:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/ssdt/thread/0c763f98-c55a-44a7-9100-80a6d9223d04

This is a free-to-use Beta build. We're currently looking for community feedback before we merge this feature into the full release.